# Vue problema ao popular os selects com arquivo json de dados

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

Boa tarde !

Estou iniciando os meus estudos com o Vue e estou enfrentando dificuldade em popular os selects da minha página. Segue abaixo os códigos:

**A view:**

Componente de mensagem

```
<div>
  <form id="burger-form">
    <div class="input-container">
     <label for="nome">Nome do cliente:</label>
       <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" v-model="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome">
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
     <label for="pao">Escolha o pão:</label>
       <select name="pao" id="pao" v-model="pao">
        <option value="">Selecione o seu pão</option>
        <option v-for="ingrediente in ingredientes.paes" :key="ingrediente.paes.id" :value="paes.tipo">{{ ingrediente.paes.tipo }}</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
     <label for="carne">Escolha a carne do seu Burger:</label>
       <select name="carne" id="carne" v-model="carne">
         <option value="">Selecione a carne</option>
        <option v-for="carne in carnes" :key="carne.id" :value="carne.tipo">{{ carne.tipo }}</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    
    <div id="opcionais-container" class="input-container">
     <label id="opcionais-title" for="opcionais">Escolha os opcionais:</label>
     <div class="checkbox-container" v-for="opcional in opcionaisdata" :key="opcional.id" >
        <input type="checkbox" name="opcionais" v-model="opcionais" :value="opcional.tipo">
        <span>{{ opcional.tipo}}</span>            
     </div>
     
                  
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
        <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Criar meu Burger !">
    </div>
   
  </form>
 </div>
```

**O script desta view:**

```
 import api from '@/services/api';
```

export default {

```
name: "BurgerForm",
data(){
    return{
                                                                                                                   
       ingredientes:{}           
    }
},    

mounted(){
    api.get('/ingredientes').then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        this.ingredientes = response.data;
    });
    

}
```

}

A minha API:

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

const api = axios.create({
baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/'
});

export default api;

**Meu banco, em json:**

```
{
"ingredientes": {
  "paes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "tipo": "Italiano Branco"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "tipo": "3 Queijos"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "tipo": "Parmesão e Orégano"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "tipo": "Integral"
    }
  ],
  "carnes": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "tipo": "Maminha"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "tipo": "Alcatra"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "tipo": "Picanha"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "tipo": "Veggie burger"
    }
  ],
  "opcionais": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "tipo": "Bacon"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "tipo": "Cheddar"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "tipo": "Salame"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "tipo": "Tomate"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "tipo": "Cebola roxa"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "tipo": "Pepino"
    }
  ]
},
"status": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "tipo": "Solicitado"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "tipo": "Em produção"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "tipo": "Finalizado"
  }
],
"burgers": []
```

}

Os dados do json estão chegando no front-end porém não estão sendo carregados nos selects.

Answer (score 1):

Você não está usando o v-for corretamente. Tem que usar o valor de cada iteração corretamente. Por exemplo:

```
v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"
```

Então no primeiro:

```
<option v-for="ingrediente in ingredientes.paes" :key="ingrediente.id">{{ ingrediente.tipo }}</option>
```

Na segunda você está usando uma variavel que não está definida 'carnes',seria ingredientes.carnes

Recomendo você ver a documentação do VUE https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: Muito obrigado Abrão ! Vou ler a documentação. Estou tendo dificuldade de entender a lógica de inserir uma coleção dentro de um outro documento ... principalmente  na parte do controller, o model e o router estou entendendo.